# list.append and list.expand new object copies over all previous entries python

Tags: python, list, append

When I index new objects into my list, the newest added object copies to all the previously added objects of the list. I have a small Python program running on a RPI3 taking input from 4 buttons.

```
    full = []
    schedule = ['day', 'activity', 'clock']
    n = 4
    def setDay(x):
        while True:
            input_state18 = GPIO.input(18)
            input_state23 = GPIO.input(23)
            input_state24 = GPIO.input(24)
            input_state25 = GPIO.input(25)
            if input_state23 == False:
                    print('Monday')
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    x[0] = 'Monday'
                    break
            if input_state18 == False:
                    print('Tuesday')
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    x[0] = 'Tuesday'
                    break
            if input_state24 == False:
                    print('Wednesday')
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    x[0] = 'Wednesday'
                    break
            if input_state25 == False:
                    print('Thursday')
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    x[0] = 'Thursday'
                    break


    def setActivity(x): 
#same as setDay
    def setClock(x):    
#same as setDay                     

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            setDay(schedule)
            setActivity(schedule)
            setClock(schedule)
            full.insert(i, schedule)
            i += 1
        #put schedule into first spot in total list 
    print(full)
```

When I run the program I get the following output into my terminal:

```
Monday
Study
19:00
Tuesday
Training
17:00
Monday
Swimming
19:00
Thursday
Training
17:00
[['Thursday', 'Training', '17:00'], ['Thursday', 'Training', '17:00'], ['Thursday', 'Training', '17:00'], ['Thursday', 'Training', '17:00']]
```

So the problem is located around my while loop in the main function. I tried using list.append as well but I got the same output. How do I change my while loop so the added lists don't replace the previous?

Comment: Appending `schedule` does not create a copy; you re-use the same list over and over. Create a *new* list each iteration (move `schedule = [...]` into the loop) or create a copy (see the duplicate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of cleanup required in this code. But the easiest way right now to make it run so that you get the desired output is:

```
 while i < n:
        # Defined within the while loop
        schedule = ['day', 'activity', 'clock']
        setDay(schedule)
        setActivity(schedule)
        setClock(schedule)
        full.insert(i, schedule)
```

Because, right now you are passing the same reference of the list to functions again, and appending the same list to the `full` list. Instead, you need new list element each time which you should be adding to the `full`.

Comment: fairly new to coding, so would be glad to here your cleanup critique.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mostly handled using references, thus appending will not copy the `schedule`, it will just append it's reference.

A trick about this is using the module copy.

```
import copy

full.insert(i, copy.deepcopy(schedule))
```

This will still append a reference, but a reference to the copied object.
This should probably help you in this case